# Where to find IT freelancers, willing to relocate to join security cleared projects at EU agencies?

Tags: contracts, freelance-websites, project, information-technology, eu

Hello I'm a sourcer looking for adventurous freelancers, who like travelling to differnet European cities and would like to obtain security clearance and join short-term and long-term EU projects. Can I post a job offer here? Is there any group that would be best for this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Someone who wants to get a security clearance is not likely to be an adventurous freelancer. Generally speaking, those are two different personality types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Freelancing site isn't any form of employment agency.  Any posts of job offers will almost certainly be taken down as spam.

You used to be able to post job offers through careers.stackoverflow.com.  However it is my understanding that this is no longer possible, see [Sunsetting Jobs & Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293/2870922).

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful!